# Восстановление файлов fat

Tags: файлы

по какой-то причине на флешке ещё в фотоаппарате пропали все фотки. gparted и другие утилиты показывают, что значительный кусок места на устройстве занят файлами, но доступа к ним нет - просто пустые директории. пробовал восстановить scalpel'ем - он вытягивает все файлы, что там были, только в каком-то неведомом формате: каждая из 140 фоток весит 150 мб (флешка на 1гб) и естесственно она ничем не открывается. как извлечь данные? )

Comment: Norton Undelete или как то [так][1].[1]: http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=23:41822

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам пригодится [это](http://user.hashcode.ru/questions/7265/windows-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) (и бесплатная [r.saver](http://rlab.ru/tools/rsaver.html) вместо r-studio), если проблема в извлечении данных с носителя. Если проблема в формате файлов, приведите его "внутренности" (или ссылку на него).